# Ember.js Array observer

Tags: ember.js

I have the following observer:

```
testArrayObserver: function(){
....

}.observes('testArray.@each'),
```

Now, this observer will hit whenever any changes are made to array may an element gets added or removed.

I want to asked that when ever this observer hits, can we know the reason i.e. weather adding element to array invoked the observer or removing an element from the array invoked the observer.

Comment: `testArray.@each` was removed in 2.0 because of performance problems, and because it's not what you usually want. The supported syntaxes are `testArray.[]` for insertion|deletion, and `testArray.@each.property`.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to know how it changed unless you cache the old value and compare, the change notification that gets triggered is generic.

Comment: @Deepak Negi Sunny can you talk about the motivation for your question? What are you actually trying to accomplish? Is it something you could use a computed property for or something that makes more sense in the code that **Does** the addition/removal?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to asked that when ever this observer hits, can we know the
>   reason i.e. weather adding element to array invoked the observer or
>   removing an element from the array invoked the observer.

No, we can't. Ember hasn't got any public API which you could use to get this information. You could however create your own logic to keep track last length of array and current length of this array. Based on comparison of these 2 numbers you could figure out whether element has been added or removed.

And using `testArray.@each` is deprecated. You'd better use:

```
testArrayObserver: Ember.observer('testArray.[]', function() {
  // ...
}),
```